# HTTP 403 with Angular 2 and it is asking for an authorization header to identify yourself

Tags: angular, typescript

When I tried to get JSON data from an API it is asking for an authorization header even after I declared one.

My code is shown below:

```
export class MyService {

 constructor(private http: Http) { }// 


headers: {

 'Authorization': "sai",   
 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
 }
   fetchData(){      
  return this.http.get('https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books')
 .map((response)=>response.json())     
 .subscribe((data)=>console.log(data),(error)=>console.log(error))
 }  }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post precisely the error message? It's likely the problem is the format of your authorization header

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and the error is :                          
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)                                    
body:"{"error":"Please provide an Authorization header to identify yourself (can be whatever you want)"}"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the `headers` into your request. Your request should look like this:

```
headers = {
  'Authorization': "sai",   
  'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
};
this.http.get('https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books', headers)
...
```